# How would I go about solving this Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have just come out of a test where this was one of the questions, I have given it more thought at home and I still don't really see what rule I should use to solve this.

The question reads roughly as:

Given $f:[0, 1]\to (-6,6)$ Calculate the following integral if $f(0)=\sqrt{35}$ and $f(1)=\sqrt{27}$

$$\int_0^1\frac{(f(x))^3f'(x)}{\sqrt{36-(f(x))^2}} \, dx$$

I am not sure about the conditions, so those might be incorrect, but the integral is this one for sure. I was only able to get to the realization that the integral was equivalent to: $\int_0^1\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^4}{\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{-1}(\frac{f(x)}{6}))} \, dx$

Comment: Change of variable: $y=(f(x))^2$.

Comment: A technicality: we would need the derivative to be integrable on $[0,1]$ for this integral to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint in comments, substitute $u=f^2,\frac{du}{dx}=2ff'$:
$$I=\frac12\int_{35}^{27}\frac u{\sqrt{36-u}}\,du=\frac12\cdot\frac{-380}3=-\frac{190}3$$

Comment: I really thought it would involve trigonometric integrals... I see now if you substitute $u=f^2$ then $dx=\frac{du}{2ff′}$ it cancels out like this $\int_{35}^{27}\frac{uf(x)f'(x)}{\sqrt{36-u}}\frac{1}{2f(x)f'(x)}dx$ Leaving only $u$

Answer (score 0):

When you see $f'(x)\,dx,$ if you don't immediately think of $u=f(x)$ and $du = f'(x)\,dx,$ then you may have missed part of the idea of how substitutions work. This substitution yields
$$
\int_{f(0)}^{f(1)} \frac{u^3}{\sqrt{36-u^2}} \, du = \int_{\sqrt{35}}^{\sqrt{27}} \frac{u^3}{\sqrt{36-u^2}} \, du.
$$
Then if you write this as $\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{35}}^{\sqrt{27}} \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{36-u^2}}\Big( u\, du\Big)$ then $\text{“}\Big(u\, du \Big)\text{”}$ suggests either $v=u^2$ or $v=36-u^2,$ and you can see why the latter brings about more simplification than the former. You get
$$
\int_1^9 \frac{36-v^2}{\sqrt v} \Big(\tfrac 1 2 \, dv\Big) = \frac 1 2\int_1^9 \left( 36 v^{-1/2} - v^{3/2} \right) \, dv
$$
and so on.